# Sending large byte array to php server

Tags: java, http, url, byte

I try to send video files (.mp4) to a server. I know that sending byte arrays is a pretty outdated method, but the problem is that I cant change the server, not allowed to.

When sending files smaller than 1 mb, everything is fine, but with larger files it doesnt work. does anyone know how to solve that?? Is it possible at all?

Server code: (in $data is the actual byte array, the 128 characters in front are just for file management, like file name and id)

```
 <?php

//get data
if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA))
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");

//cass -------------------------------------------------------------
$filename = substr($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, 0, 128);    
$filename = trim($filename, " ");               
$filename = explode(";",$filename);     
$fname = $filename[0];
$q_id = $filename[1];
$data = substr($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, 128);

$length = strlen($data);

$file = fopen("cassDebug.txt","w");
$textout = "QID: $q_id NAME: $fname LENGTH: $length";

fwrite($file,$textout);
fclose($file);

// write file
if(strlen($data)>0){
        $FSize = strlen($data);
        $f = fopen("media/$fname",'w');
        fwrite($f,$data,$FSize);
         fclose($f);
 }

?>
```

Java code:

```
try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

    connection.connect();

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

    String fileName = makeLength(fname, fname.length());
    String comma = ";";
    String audioQuestionId = makeLength(QID, 128 - fname.length() - comma.length());

    os.write(fileName.getBytes());
    os.write(comma.getBytes());
    os.write(audioQuestionId.getBytes());

    // Initialize byte array for data transfer
    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[2*1024];

    // Get total bytes in the file
            long totalBytes = fileInputStream.available();

            System.out.println("Total bytes: "+totalBytes);

            long bytesRead = 0; 
        int n = 0;
        while ((n = fileInputStream.read(dataBuffer, 0, 2*1024)) != -1) {
              os.write(dataBuffer, 0, n);
              bytesRead += n;
        }

            System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());

    fileInputStream.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    connection.disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [php.ini](http://www.fengoffice.com/web/wiki/doku.php/php.ini) file. The default POST limit is 1MB. You probably didn't raise it.